# Flex 4 change skin part value

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, visibility, skin

Hello
I would like to change the visibility of specific part of the skin at run time, but i dont know how to reach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "reach it"?

Both the component class and the skin class have a reference to the skin part by using that component's name.  How I would usually hide a skin part at run time is using this process:

1) Create a new Skin State; something like "skinPartHidden"

2) In the Component class; create a skinPartVisible property.  When the property value is changed; call the invalidateSkinState() method.  This will cause getCurrentSkinState() to run during the next render event.

3) In the get getCurrentSkinState() method; use that property's value to set the skin state to your new skinPartHidden skin state.  Something like his:

```
if(skinPartVisible == false){
 return "skinPartHidden";
}
```

4) In the skin class; toggle the visibility of the skin Part based on the skin state using the MXML state Syntax.  Something like this:

`visible.skinPartHidden="true"`

Comment: Thank You very much Jeffry Houser. Your solution really point me to the answers I were looking for. The things now looks much more clear to me :) Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what part do you want to hide/reveal. If you're talking about some skin specific graphics (which is not represented as `[SkinPart]` declaration in a host component) then you can implement two strategies:

- Your hide/reveal logic is just a part of view but no the component functionality. In this case you should extend your skin and place hide/reveal logic there. You can use data binding of properties of `hostComponent`.
- Your hide/reveal logic adds some new functionality. Extend your component and introduce some new view state or declare target skin part there and change visibility in a component on some property change. In this case it is possible you'll have to change skin too.

For changing visibility of known declared skin part you can use the modifications of strategies listed above. In the second strategy you needn't to declare skin part :)

Comment: When building MXML Skins; Adobe recommends against extending skins.  The tooling doesn't support it; including Flash Catalyst and Flash Builder.

Comment: Sorry for expressing this not so clear way. As extending skin I mean just copy/paste of original skin and then modify it methodology :)

Comment: Thank you Constantiner about your kind answer, you point me aswell to things i had to read in order to complete a few things. Thank you.